# Setting ACL on Cloud Storage file with PHP on App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need to set the mime-type for a file after writing it to Google Storage with GD imagejpeg(), since this function does not support stream contexts. Since PHP rename supports stream context I thought it might work to set it when renaming the file, but apparently this does not work:

```
imagejpeg($image,$tmpfilename);
$ctx = stream_context_create(['gs'=>['acl'=>'public-read','Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']]);
$ok =    rename($tmpfilename,$filename,$ctx);
```

What other options than reading the file back into memory and writing it back to CloudStorage do I have with the PHP Google AppEngine API?

Comment: Well, I ended up using stream_context_set_default() and stream_context_set_default(). Which I kind of dislike…

Comment: This should have been fixed already.